# Words from LDA output pyspark machine learning

Tags: nlp, lda, pyspark

I built a pipeline for an LDA model using pyspark's machine learning.

Here is my code:

```
 tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol='formatted_transcript',
 outputCol='words')

 stopWordsRemover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words",
 outputCol="filtered")

 vectorizer = CountVectorizer(inputCol="filtered",
 outputCol="features", vocabSize=40000, minDF=5.0)

 lda = LDA(k=10, maxIter=10)

 pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, stopWordsRemover, vectorizer,
 lda])

 pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(DF_with_formatted)
```

When I print the results:

```
print(pipelineModel.stages[3].describeTopics(5).show(truncate=False))
```

I see the termIndices and termWeights, but not the actual words. How do I obtain the words corresponding to the termIndices?

Answer (score 0):

With help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44233862/visualizing-topics-with-spark-lda), I came up with the following solution:

```
vocab = pipelineModel.stages[2].vocabulary 
topics = pipelineModel.stages[3].describeTopics(5)  
topics_rdd = topics.rdd
topics_words = topics_rdd\
       .map(lambda row: row['termIndices'])\
       .map(lambda idx_list: [vocab[idx] for idx in idx_list])\
       .collect()

for idx, topic in enumerate(topics_words):
    print("topic: ", idx)
    print("----------")

    for word in topic:
        print(word)
        print("----------")
```